# Concatenating dataframes in a loop very slow

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I am building one "master" dataframes by concatenating in a *for* loop

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(listdf)], axis = 1)
```

listdf is the temp list for preprocessing before it is concatenated to the dataframe.
The problem I am facing is that as the number of iterations of the loop increases, process of building the dataframe gets slower and slower.

I have researched here and based on this suggestion, it is much faster to build a list and then to finally concatenate it into a dataframe
[Why does concatenation of DataFrames get exponentially slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower)

However this approach is not working

```
interimdf.append(listdf)
df = pd.concat(interimdf)
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

How do I resolve this issue. Also there is an alternative way to speed up the process to create one big dataframe in a loop

Comment: What is the type of listdf?  `type(listdf)`  For this to work, listdf must by a pd.Series or pd.DataFrame.

Comment: It is of the type list

Comment: I not sure if this will work for you, but looking at your post here.  Try this instead `interimdf.append(pd.DataFrame(listdf))`

Comment: That worked awesomely. Blazing fast now. Earlier it was taking me 3-4 hrs to run that loop and now it finishes in less than a second. Thanks

Comment: Awesome.   I glad this worked for you.  Yeah, I will remember the "quadratic copying" problem.  I submitted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append dataframes to your list and not the data as list.

Try:

```
interimdf.append(pd.DataFrame(listdf))
```

Then outside of your loop,

```
pd.concat(interimdf)
```